# glRenderbufferStorage GL_INVALID_ENUM

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

Following [OpenGL ES Programming Guide IOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html) I use `glRenderbufferStorage` in setting up my FBO. In the guide it says use:

```
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8, width, height);
```

In my code (since GL_RGBA8 is undefined), I use

```
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8_OES, width, height);
```

and it throws a GL_INVALID_ENUM exception. Is this the correct way to setup an FBO? This is an OpenGL ES 2.0 project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document is a bit weird, I haven't managed to get it working following the guide and I too don't have that GL_RGBA8 enum. Quite annoyed really.

Anyhow, for the colorRenderBuffer, the way it is shown on Ray Wenderlich's (also on that Apple documentation if you scroll down a bit in the "on-screen frame buffer") site is like so:

```
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderBuffer);
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:eglLayer];
```

That Apple documentation seems to be outdated.